# Can't start Protractor e2e-Test in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Version-Infos:

- chromedriver: 2.33
- npm: 5.5.1
- nodejs: 8.9.0
- openjdk version:
    1.8.0_141
- docker-image: openjdk:8

Here's my problem: I want to start e2e-Tests with Protractor on Jenkins. I'm running a docker-container for building the whole application as well the tests. I'm installing chrome and chromedriver in the container. I start the driver with `webdriver-manager start`. Now the problem is that when Jenkins wants to start the e2e-Tests, it crashes with the following error:

```
[15:05:17] I/file_manager - creating folder /data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[15:05:18] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.33.zip
[15:05:18] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.33
[15:05:18] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:05:18] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[15:06:19] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.74-92.29-default x86_64)
[15:06:19] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.74-92.29-default x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.ts:90:25)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A/ebd-web-ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[15:06:19] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
script returned exit code 199
```

The part of my Jenkinsfile, where I install node, npm, chromedriver and so on:

```
sh 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl'
sh 'curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -'
sh 'apt-get install -y nodejs'
sh 'npm config set registry="https://nexus3.eap.bit.admin.ch/repository/npm-all/"'
sh 'npm config set strict-ssl false'
sh "java -version"
sh "nodejs --version"
sh "npm --version"
sh 'wget -q -O - https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian/cli.cloudfoundry.org.key | apt-key add -'
sh 'echo "deb http://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudfoundry-cli.list'
sh 'apt-get update'
sh 'apt-get install -y cf-cli'
sh 'cf --version'
sh 'date'
sh 'npm install protractor -g'
sh 'webdriver-manager update'

sh 'sh -c \'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list\''
sh 'wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'

sh 'apt-get update'
sh 'apt-get install -y libxpm4 libxrender1 libgtk2.0-0 libnss3 libgconf-2-4 '
sh 'apt-get install -y libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 xdg-utils'

sh 'wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
sh 'dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
sh 'apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable'

sh 'apt-get install -y xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf'
sh 'apt-get install -y xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-scalable'
sh 'apt-get install -y imagemagick x11-apps dbus-x11'

sh 'Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 & export DISPLAY=:99'
sh 'webdriver-manager start &'
```

Output when I start webdriver-manager:

```
[ature_ChromeHeadlessJenkins-I3N4DKAF3MHS72RV35MYVEHTF7OCMJ2VQKG54JMW2L7IQHOYN66A] Running shell script
+ webdriver-manager start
[15:33:18] I/start - java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.33 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.19.1 -jar /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -port 4444
[15:33:18] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 17381
14:33:19.123 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767'
14:33:19.124 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-11-01 14:33:19.151:INFO::main: Logging initialized @292ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
14:33:19.211 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
14:33:19.237 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
14:33:19.237 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
14:33:19.237 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX
14:33:19.258 INFO - Using the passthrough mode handler
2017-11-01 14:33:19.279:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
2017-11-01 14:33:19.313:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a5ed7a6{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
2017-11-01 14:33:19.318:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a5ed7a6{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-11-01 14:33:19.333:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@694e1548{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-11-01 14:33:19.333:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @474ms
14:33:19.333 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

Does anyone knows a solution or has an idea how to get rid of this? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran in to this same issue getting my Protractor tests to run on Jenkins.  Unfortunately I never actually figured out what caused the problem, but I did discover that when running the Selenium Server from a standalone JAR (https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-server-standalone-jar) webdriver was able to connect properly for whatever reason.  I'd be curious if that works for you.

More details provided by OP:

1. I installed the Selenium standalone JAR with NPM

`sudo npm install selenium-server-standalone-jar`

2. I edited my protractor.conf.js like this:

   `multiCapabilities: [
           {browserName: 'chrome',
           chromeOptions: {args:['no-sandbox','--headless','disable-gpu']}} 
       ],
       //directConnect: true, 
       //seleniumAddress: 'http://172.17.0.2:4444/wd/hub',
       seleniumServerJar :'./node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar'`

   - added headless and disable-gpu
   - deleted directConnect
   - deleted seleniumAdress (because it will overwrite selenium server in some way)
   - added the path to jar (seleniumServerJar)

Comment: Could you share your protractor.conf.js if possible? I get a ECONNREFUSED when I start the selenium server with `webdriver-manager start --standalone`. @J. Paul

Comment: I just have the location of the JAR as part of my exports.config:

        `exports.config = {
        getPageTimeout: 20000,
        seleniumServerJar: 'selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar',
        params: {
    ...`


Then I don't need to do anything with webdriver-manager, protractor starts the server when it runs the tests.  Hope that helps.

Edit.... Oh, I see you figured that out on your own.  nice.